# Downloading Pillow for Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to download Pillow on my mac, which has python version 2.7.6. I have been following the instructions 
[here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/installation.html#basic-installation) and have a problem when running `pip install Pillow`.

The error message that I get is

> Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
>     Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Pillow

Is there something wrong with that URL? Does anyone know how to proceed with the download?

Comment: Your issue seems unrelated to pillow but something is certainly wrong. I would try to upgrade pip to see if that's helps: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Are you blocking https (a proxy perhaps) at all? The error itself could be indicating PIP could not reach https://pypi.python.org/simple/, the page that it searches for packages.

Comment: Try with pip install pillow=version. Exact <version> would sometimes work.

Comment: @Wolph Thanks for the suggestion. I tried upgrading pip via 'pip install -U pip'. However, I get a very similar error (replace the last word Pillow with 'pip' and some local address).

Comment: @tgikal Not that I know of, although I don't know of a way to check more conclusively than pointing my browser to https sites.

Comment: As Python3 has been out 11 years, and as you appear to be starting from zero, I would suggest you consider installing Python3 with **homebrew** and life will be easier.

Comment: @C.Williamson you should be able to go to https://pypi.python.org/simple/ it's just a bunch of links.

Comment: I didn't really notice the mac part, but I strongly agree with Mark here. The bundled Python versions in OS X are always lagging behind quite a bit, using homebrew will make your life much easier